# Запятая перед "как"?

Tags: запятые

> Рентабельность мясного козоводства практически такая же(?) как у
>   свиноводства.

Нужна ли запятая перед словом "как"? Мне кажется, что да, но я не уверена.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запятая нужна.

Розенталь:
Сравнительный оборот с союзом *как* выделяется запятыми, если в основной части предложения имеется указательное слово (*так, такой, тот, столь*):
*Нигде при взаимной встрече не раскланиваются так благородно и непринуждённо, как на Невском проспекте.

Лаевский безусловно вреден и **так же** опасен для общества, как холерная микроба.

Всё вокруг какое-то церковное, и маслом пахнет **так же** крепко, как в церкви.

Я всё сделаю, чтобы стать **такой**, как она.

Ямщик был **в таком же** изумлении от его щедрости, как и сам француз от предложения Дубровского.

Черты лица его были **те же**, как и у сестры.

Редко встречаешь **столь** интересного человека, как он.*

Без указательного слова запятая бы в данном примере не ставилась:
*Рентабельность мясного козоводства практически как у свиноводства.*